# How to add a setTimeout to a Random MP3 List

Tags: javascript, arrays

The following script works well on a web page to randomize the MP3s that play from the list below, but I would like the MP3s to start playing at about ten seconds later, after page load, with a setTimeout.
How is it done correctly?

The following script works well on a web page to randomize the MP3s that play from the list below, but I would like the MP3s to start playing at about ten seconds later, after page load, with a setTimeout.
How is it done correctly?

```
<script>
    var audio; 
    var playlist; 
    var tracks; 
    var current; 
    var musicarr = [

    "After the Sun.mp3",
    "Dreamlight.mp3",
    "Shadows of the moon.mp3",
                   ];    

    shuffle(musicarr);

    init();
    function init(){
        current = 0;
        audio = $('audio');
        audio[0].volume = .7;

        len = musicarr.length;

        run(musicarr[current], audio[0]);

        audio[0].addEventListener('ended',function(e){
            current++;
            if(current == len){
                current = 0;
            }
            run(musicarr[current],audio[0]);
        });
    }

    function run(link, player){
            player.src = link;
            audio[0].load();
            audio[0].play();    
    }

    function shuffle(array) {
      var currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex ;

      // While there remain elements to shuffle...
      while (0 !== currentIndex) {

        // Pick a remaining element...
        randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
        currentIndex -= 1;


        // And swap it with the current element.
        temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
        array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
        array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
      }

      return array;
    }

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the init() call you have just above function init(){...} then add the following at the bottom of the script:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
     setTimeout(init, 10000); // 10 * 1000 = 10 seconds
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply and help bob. The setTimeout as you wrote it works great.